# Python matplotlib, timestamp on graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have a simple basic script below that will create a scatter plot of some data and I was curious if its possible for a date & time stamp ***of when the graph was created*** to be incorporated on the plot as well?... Like something small in a corner of the plot or something??... Thanks for any tips

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\HVAC-AHU-Economizer-Diagnostics-master\\AHU3 data CSV.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)


OAT = pd.Series(df['OAT'])
RAT = pd.Series(df['RAT'])
MAT = pd.Series(df['MAT'])

df_OATrat = (OAT - RAT)
df_MATrat = (MAT - RAT)

plt.scatter(df_OATrat,df_MATrat, color='grey', marker='+')
plt.xlabel('OAT-RAT')
plt.ylabel('MAT-RAT')
plt.title('Economizer Diagnostics')

plt.plot([0,-18],[0,-18], color='green', label='100% OSA during ideal conditions')
plt.plot([0,20],[0,5], color='red', label='Minimum OSA in cooling mode')
plt.plot([0,-38],[0,-9.5], color='blue', label='Minimum OSA in heating mode')
plt.plot([0,0],[-20,10], color='black')
plt.plot([-30,20],[0,0], color='black')
plt.legend()

plt.savefig('static/plot.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a text box, with the value of datetime.now():
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Comment: I'd argue this is a comment.  To make this more useful, show the example applied to OP's scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am happy with the results using the `time` module `time.ctime()`